# General issues with access to and from DMZ on Cisco ASA 5520

Tags: cisco-asa, networking

I just got my software upgraded from v8.2(x) to v.9.1(7), but I have some general issues with access to and from my DMZ:

1. No internet access from DMZ
2. No access to web or mail server from outside to DMZ

Here is my running-config:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 109.xxx.yyy.zzz 255.255.255.128
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 nameif data
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Management0/0
 nameif mgmt
 security-level 0
 ip address 192.168.128.1 255.255.255.0
!
...
object network obj-dmz-subnet
 subnet 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network obj-lan-subnet
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj-data-subnet
 subnet 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
object network obj-mgmt-subnet
 subnet 192.168.128.0 255.255.255.0
object network web_server
 host 172.16.1.30
object network web_server_http
 host 172.16.1.30
object network web_server_https
 host 172.16.1.30
object network mail_server_smtp
 host 172.16.1.40
object network mail_server_pop3
 host 172.16.1.40
object network mail_server_imap
 host 172.16.1.40
object network mail_server_pop3s
 host 172.16.1.40
object network mail_server_imaps
 host 172.16.1.40
object network mail_server_smtps
 host 172.16.1.40
object-group network web_servers
 network-object host 172.16.1.30
object-group network mail_servers
 network-object host 172.16.1.40
object-group service web_services tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service mail_services tcp
 port-object eq smtp
 port-object eq imap4
 port-object eq pop3
 port-object eq 995
 port-object eq 993
 port-object eq 465
object-group service zabbix_services tcp
 port-object eq 10050
 port-object eq 10051
access-list ACL_IN extended permit ip any4 any4
access-list OUTSIDE_TO_DMZ extended permit ip any4 any4
access-list OUTSIDE_TO_DMZ extended permit tcp any object-group web_servers object-group web_services
access-list OUTSIDE_TO_DMZ extended permit tcp any object-group mail_servers object-group mail_services
access-list OUTSIDE_TO_DMZ extended deny ip any any log
access-list DMZ_TO_INSIDE extended permit tcp object obj-dmz-subnet host 192.168.1.4 object-group zabbix_services
!
object network obj-dmz-subnet
 nat (dmz,outside) dynamic interface
object network obj_any
 nat (dmz,outside) dynamic interface
object network obj-lan-subnet
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
object network web_server_http
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp www www
object network web_server_https
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp https https
object network mail_server_smtp
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp smtp smtp
object network mail_server_pop3
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp pop3 pop3
object network mail_server_imap
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp imap4 imap4
object network mail_server_pop3s
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp 995 995
object network mail_server_imaps
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp 993 993
object network mail_server_smtps
 nat (dmz,outside) static interface service tcp 465 465
access-group OUTSIDE_TO_DMZ in interface outside
access-group DMZ_TO_INSIDE in interface dmz
access-group ACL_IN in interface inside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 109.xxx.yyy.zzz 1
```

What am I missing in my configuration?

Edit:
The NAT statement clean-up was the solution to one of the problems. Now I have full access to my web and mail server. However, Internet access to the DMZ still fails.
Here is the result of the packet-tracer command "packet-tracer input dmz tcp 172.16.1.100 80 8.8.8.8 80":

```
Phase: 1
Type: ROUTE-LOOKUP
Subtype: input
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
in   0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         outside

Phase: 2
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype: 
Result: DROP
Config:
Implicit Rule
Additional Information:

Result:
input-interface: dmz
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: outside
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
```

**Edit**: I think I have made everything work now. It helped insert the following access list:

```
access-list FROM_DMZ extended permit ip any any
```

Now I can send ping commands to the big wide world and get my machines upgraded in the DMZ.
It seemed almost too easy. Is there something I have to take into account or something I have forgotten?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89646/discussion-on-question-by-soren-sjostrom-general-issues-with-access-to-and-from).

Comment: Nope. That access-list entry was the final missing piece. I can't say that I feel comfortable with you having it set to allow all IP protocols and all ports, but it's your decision. I prefer to only allow protocols I know are actually needed, like TCP/80 and TCP/443 (like the example I provided earlier).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's clean up your NAT statements a bit before we troubleshoot.

Here, we'll temporarily remove your "global" NAT statements

```
 object network obj-dmz-subnet
     no nat (dmz,outside) dynamic interface
 object network obj-lan-subnet
     no nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
```

This next object is a default object created on ASAs, which has a corresponding NAT statement that has been known to cause problems (due to how broad it is)  if you don't remove it.  You aren't using it, from what I can see, so we will remove it completely.

```
no object network obj_any
```

The next 2 lines are to create your global NAT statements again, but as manual NATs (rather than auto NATs) and also using the after-auto keyword in each to make sure that they are only used as a sort of last-resort (if traffic doesn't match against any other NAT statement first).

```
nat (dmz,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
nat (inside,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
```

Now that the NAT statements are in a bit better order, can you show me some packet-tracer outputs?

```
packet-tracer input dmz tcp 172.16.1.100 1234 8.8.8.8 80

packet-tracer input outside tcp 8.8.8.8 1234 <your public IP for your web-server> 80
```

Edit:

Please add:

`access-list DMZ_TO_INSIDE extended permit tcp object obj-dmz-subnet any eq 80`

along with

`access-list DMZ_TO_INSIDE extended permit tcp object obj-dmz-subnet any eq 443`

and then perform the same packet-tracer command as you tried a moment ago. The reason it didn't work before is because you currently only allow the DMZ subnet to access your Zabbix servers.

I would suggest, since we are now NOT limiting your DMZ to only access the Zabbix servers, that you rename your DMZ access-list to make more sense.

If you want to rename your access-list, you can do so by using the command:

```
access-list DMZ_TO_INSIDE rename <new name>
```

For example: `access-list DMZ_TO_INSIDE rename from_DMZ`

FYI, renaming an access-list (or object) has no impact on traffic, as ASAs use an access-list and/or object's hex ID, not its name, which does not change by using the rename command.  This means you can change it without fear of impacting users/servers.